Turborepo Internal Package - The requested module does not provide an export named 'default'
I have a monorepo project using turborepo. All apps are under the name "@repo" (I'm committing the company name).
I'm constantly getting errors like:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '' does not provide an export named 'default'.

It works fine when I build and serve the output, I get no errors, but in dev mode, I'm constantly facing errors.
I have one package called "@repo/utils", this repo contains some utils functions and its tslint is the following
{
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.jsonc",
  "include": ["src", "vitest.config.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["vitest/globals", "@testing-library/jest-dom", "vite/client"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "docs"]
}

and base.jsonc
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Default",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "ESNext.Array", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": false,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "build"],
}

In the package.json I have "type": "module" and I don't have a build script since it's meant to be a just-in-time package.
I have another package named @repo/ui
Where I have the UI components and this is my tsconfig
{
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.json",
  "include": ["src", "vite.config.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vite/client", "vitest/globals", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": { "@/*": ["src/*"] }
  }
}


and this is my vite.config.ts
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import { glob } from 'glob';
import { basename, dirname, extname, relative, resolve } from 'node:path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import { libInjectCss } from 'vite-plugin-lib-inject-css';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), libInjectCss(), dts({ insertTypesEntry: true })],
  resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      // map all index.ts and index.tsx files as entry points
      // this allows import { Button } from '@repo/ui/Button' instead of
      // import { Button } from '@repo/ui'
      entry: Object.fromEntries(
        glob
          .sync('src/**/*.{ts,tsx}')
          .filter((file) => basename(file, extname(file)) === 'index')
          .map((file) => [
            relative('src', dirname(file)).replace(/\\/g, '/'), // Use relative path from 'src' as key
            resolve(__dirname, file),
          ]),
      ),
      formats: ['es'],
    },
    sourcemap: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react/jsx-runtime'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          'react/jsx-runtime': 'react/jsx-runtime',
        },
        chunkFileNames: 'chunks/[name].[hash].js',
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[name][extname]',
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
      },
    },
  },
});


I also have another package named "@repo/auth" which has login page and some zustand store for handling authentication
This is the tsconfig
{
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.json",
  "include": ["src", "vitest.config.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["vitest/globals", "@testing-library/jest-dom", "vite/client"],
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "docs"]
}

And also in the package.json I have "type": "module" and I don't have a build script because it's meant to be a just-in-time package.
I have two apps that import @repo/auth, @repo/utils and @repo/ui
I'm facing the problem with all of them. If I can fix the first one I can fix the second because both are react vite apps.
The first has the following tsconfig
{
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.json",
  "include": ["src", "vite.config.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vite/client", "vitest/globals", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": { "@/*": ["src/*"] }
  }
}


and vite.config.ts
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgr()],
  resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['@repo/utils', '@repo/auth', '@repo/ui'],
  },
});


in package.json I have "type": "module", and the build script is tsc -b && vite build
My first error was

SyntaxError: The requested module '/repo/@fs/C:/repo/node_modules/crypto-js/index.js?v=82625a9d' does not provide an export named 'AES' (at crypto.ts:1:10)

So I commented out the file that was using crypto-js and then I got

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/repo/@fs/C:/repo/node_modules/use-sync-external-store/shim/with-selector.js?v=f17961d5' does not provide an export named 'default' (at index.mjs:4:8)

I noticed it was related to zustand, so I commented it out
now I'm getting this

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/C:/repo/node_modules/zustand-sync-tabs/index.js?v=9fa2fc6c' does not provide an export named 'syncTabs' (at auth.ts:23:10)

Do you see where it's heading? I don't think the problem is with the external libraries but definitely with either tsconfig or vite.config.
